# Plotting complex number wrt frequency

Tags: plotting, complex, frequency

I want to plot a complex function wrt frequency. How can i do it? 
If my function as follows:

```
w=2*Pi*f;
Zc=(1/i*w*C)
Zl=(i*w*L)
Z1=(R*Zc)/(1+Zc*Zl)
```

where i==> imaginary number.
let Z1 be an imaginary number = a+ib in terms of frequency;
I want to plot phase of Z1 wrt frequency.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Try to look this : http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RLCSeriesCircuit/

Comment: better try this one: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PhasorDiagramForSeriesRLCCircuits/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally one uses transfer function in `s` and then calls `BodePlot`. Bode replaces `s` by `I w` and then plots the magnitude and phase as function of `w`.

So your question is not clear.  You give no context and meaning to the variables you wrote.

But may be this is can get you started. First need some numerical values for the parameters

```
ClearAll[f]
R0 = 10; C0 = 3; L0 = 4;
w = 2*Pi*f;
Zc = (1/I*w*C0)
Zl = (I*w*L0)
Z1 = (R0*Zc)/(1 + Zc*Zl)
mag = ComplexExpand[Abs@Z1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you plot the magnitudes vs. `f` in Hz as follows

```
 LogLogPlot[mag,{f,0,30},PlotRange->All,Frame->True,
    FrameLabel->{{"|mag|",None},{"frequency in Hz","my plot"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**
To answer comment.

To plot phase. It is `-Pi/2` for all frequencies.

```
Plot[ComplexExpand@Arg@Z1,{f,0,30},PlotRange->All,Frame->True,
    FrameLabel->{{"Phase",None},{"frequency in Hz","my plot"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To plot  mag vs. phase (since phase is fixed at `-Pi/2` you get straight line), you can use `ParametricPlot`

```
ParametricPlot[{mag, ComplexExpand@Arg@Z1},{f,0,30},PlotRange->All,
  Frame->True,FrameLabel->{{"Phase",None},{"|mag|","my plot"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I want exactly same thing which you gave to me .... but i want to plot the graph of phase vs freq............. what syntax i can use for phase instead of mag = ComplexExpand[Abs@Z1]

Comment: @Jadav to find phase, you use `Arg`. But it is better to use BodePlot for all these things if you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[f]
R0 = 10; C0 = 30; L0 = 4;
w[f_] = 2*Pi*f;
Zc[f_] = (1/I*w[f_]*C0)
Zl[f_] = (I*w[f_]*L0)
Z1[f_] = (R0*Zc[f_])/(1 + Zc[f_]*Zl[f_])


N[A, 3] = Abs[Trans[f]];
N[B, 3] = Arg[Trans[f]]*180/Pi;
Plot[Abs[Trans[f]], {f, 1*10^8, 10*10^9}]
Plot[Arg[Trans[f]]*180/Pi, {f, 7.8*10^9, 8.2*10^9}]
```

for magnitude

[image]

for phase
[image]

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thank you @Nasser